# jQuery load() fails to load after link back to page

Tags: jquery

I have this small script that works fine when the initial page loads. I have a menu at top of page. When I go to another page in my site and use the back button to return to home page the script still works and load the file. However when I use a link back to this page the PHP file does not load. Please can anyone advise.

```
$(window).ready(function () {
  if (screen.width < 1024) {
    $('#place_holder').load('small.php');
    return false;
  } 

  if (screen.width > 1024) {
    $('#place_holder').load('desktop-wide.php');
    return false;
  } 

  if (screen.width = 1024) {
    $('#place_holder').load('desktop-small.php');
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: So the first back button you are speaking about it's the browser one and the second one is a back button you have developed?
This is not clear for me. Can you specify in your question if you are speaking of the back button of the browser?

Comment: You can avoid the problem entirely and improve the logic and performance by using a CSS media query to change the layout based on the available screen width.

Comment: yes if use the back browser button no problem. but if use a link in my navigation bar to the home page have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to load a php file throught client, that is not possible.

You can add a new css file according to the size of the screen

```
if (screen.width < 1024) {
  $("<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>").appendTo("head");
}
```

But that is not a good practice!!!

Instead, you have to use link tag rule sets in your header, like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 1024px)" href="style1024.css" />
```

Then you have of course to create a style1024.css that contains the css rules you want to apply to 1024 screens

Or by using a `@media` css media queries rules in your stylesheet file.

```
 @media (max-width: 1024px) {
    .mydiv {
     background-color:#333;
   }
 }
```

check this doc for more infos about [css media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: I tried that but still have same problem. any suggestions please?

Comment: how your "back" link/button is made? Jquery too?

Comment: No just a normal menu with hyper link

Comment: `javascript:history.back()`  like this ?

Comment: <li><a href="index.html"><img src="images/home_btn.png" alt="" width="32" height="32" class="spacer15px"/>Home</a></li>

Comment: This is the link back to the home pages. which is on other pages in the site.

Comment: well here is the site i trying to build up take a look for yourself please.          http://ldr-visions.co.uk/index.html

Comment: Oh ok, That's because you're trying to load a php file, sorry I didn't noticed lol. That is obviously not possible. You can access a php file, like with a xhr request for example, but not loading it directly through client (it's not a css file) What you can do is to use a @media rule instead. [Check this out](https://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/)

Comment: PLEASE check my answer, I edited it, and mark as solved if it's good @LeighRendle

Comment: can't do it with media queries as it need to load adobe animate javascript   2 different scripts one for small animation mobile one for computers.

Comment: @LeighRendle Javascript is a thing, css another. Why are saying you can't call another css when on mobile because of the javascript. I don't get it

Comment: <?php
if(strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), 'mobile') || strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), 'android')) {
   include ("small.php");
}  else {
             include ("desktop-wide.php");
     }?>

Comment: If you already do it with php, why would you want a javascript solution to change css?